# How to run progress dialog while alert dialog is running

Tags: android, progressdialog, android-alertdialog

I've got an `AlertDialog` with an item list. When I click on some item of the `AlertDialog`, I want to run a `ProgressDialog`.

How can I do it?

That's a part of my code:

```
final CharSequence[] items = { "Detalles", "Reprogramarlo",
    "Ejecutarlo", "Cancelarlo", "Evaluación" };

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
    SeleccionarServicio.this);
builder.setTitle("¿Qué quiere hacer?");
builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

    if (items[item].equals("Detalles")) {


    }

    if (items[item].equals("Reprogramarlo")) {

    }

    if (items[item].equals("Ejecutarlo")) {
        //Here I want to run progress dialog

        final ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(SeleccionarServicio.this, "Medidas a Adoptar",
                "Comprobando Medidas...");
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                app.ActualizarMedidasAdoptar(clickedObject.getNumeroCliente(), clickedObject.getCodigoObra());


                pd.dismiss();

            }
        }).start();

        }                           
        });
    }

    if (items[item].equals("Cancelarlo")) {
        DilogCancelarServicio();
    }

    if (items[item].equals("Evaluación")) {

    }

}
});
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

alert.show();

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nesting dialogs is not the best idea in terms of user experience, but if you still want to do it you'll need to dismiss the Alert dialog first.

Comment: Ok, thanks for advice. I'll create new class with the same buttons that are in alert dialog list.